# VBA/excel-VBA - add two values with dot separator

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and need to add two values using VBA in Excel. I receive imported values with dot-separator and if I try to add them, the dot is ignored.

So:

```
1.12
1.34
```

should result in 2.46, but I'm getting 246

Code:

```
Do Until (Cells(iRow, 1) = 100)
  addValue = Cells(iRow, 2).Value
  dValue = dValue + addValue
  iRow = iRow + 1
  MsgBox (dValue)
Loop
```

Thanks for some 101-tips...

Here is the updated code:

```
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim addValue As Double
Dim dValue As Double

iRow = 2

Do Until (Cells(iRow, 1) = 100)
addValue = Cells(iRow, 8) 
Debug.Print "Row"; iRow; " is "; addValue 
modValue = Replace(addValue, ".", ",")
MsgBox (addValue)
newVal = Cells(iRow, 8).Value

dValue = dValue + newVal
iRow = iRow + 1

Loop
MsgBox (dValue)
```

Basically I have a lit of values like this:

```
100    header
200    1.12
200    1.34
200    1.54 
100    header
```

...

I want to sum the 200 correspondig values 1.12, 1.34, 1.54. The values show up as 112, 134 and 154.

Thanks

Comment: Would you please explain "imported values with dot-separator"? I have heard of Comma Separated Values, but never dot-separators. Do they look like American-style decimals in Excel?

Comment: if you have an update to your question, add it to the question, not another user's post.

Comment: the import file is CSV with ";" separators. However all prices in the file are x.yz format with Dot-Seperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you place this line after `addValue =`, please?

```
Debug.Print "Row"; iRow; " is "; addValue
```

Offhand, I am suspecting that the 1.12 is not really a double.

Also, did you declare your variables? Nothing fancy, but something like

```
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim addValue As Double
Dim dValue As Double
```

Finally, you may want to consider placing the MsgBox after the loop, instead of having it give a subtotal on every; iteration.

Comment: hm. Still not working. I edited your comment with the current code I have now

Comment: The Debug.Print statement was intended to debug, not fix. Go over to the Visual Basic screen where you have the code and select View -> Immediate Window. At the bottom of your screen, you should have "Row 1 is 1.12" and "Row 2 is 1.34" If it's not, then the Debug should point you the direction you need to go.

Comment: I retyped your first col into A1:A5 and your second col into H1:H5. (This was to match your 1 and 8 columns in your code.) I got 4 popups: 1.12, 1.34, 1.54, and 4. The immediate windows says "Row 2  is  1.12 
Row 3  is  1.34 
Row 4  is  1.54 " If you do not see these results in your immediate window, would you please try typing Header, 1.12, etc. into H1:H5?

Comment: Another thought, @frequent. I am using a US-version of Excel on a US-version of Windows XP. What are you using? Please select cells H2:H4, and format them. When you choose Category: Number, do you see a Sample like 1.12?

Comment: hm... if I do it in a blank file I get the same result as you. In my imported file... 1.12 = 112. So must be something with the cell format.

Comment: ok. I think I found the problem. When importing the CSV into Excel:
- when I leave field as "Standart" converts to Date
- when I change to text I'm stuck at above problem
- when I click options and select , as separator and . as .000 then I get real numbers like 1,23 and so on.

Comment: Excellent! I was going to guess that the behavior was caused by your imported file coming from, say, France. They would write the two-and-a-quarter as 2,25. But it looks like you've figured out to change the import dialogue so that it does not leave column H as General but as a number instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some funny number formatting applied to the values in Excel. Highlight the range and hit Ctrl-Shift-` (or format the cells as "General" from the format menu). I bet those numbers are actually 112 and 134.

Answer (score 0):

Right... The problem is formatting, and Excel's insistence on describing (say) '4/7' as 'Fourth of July' rather than four-sevenths*. Or indeed, as a textual 'Four-slash-seven'.

I do not know what strange format has been picked up in those 'decimal' cells, but you have two jobs to do:

1. Change the number format of those cells to 'general' so you can see
   what's actually in them, rather than whatever Excel wants to
   present;
2. Change your code to use the 'Value2' property of a range, which
   gives you the raw data instead of a formatted interpretation of the
   'value' - newVal = Cells(iRow, 8).Value2

I would also recommend that you declare NewVal as Double. This will coerce a type conversion to floating-point number, a far better idea than letting a 'variant' decide what type it would like to be, based on formatting information in a range.

I'd better warn you that task (1) works about half the time on data imported from Oracle databases, and numbers copied from spreadsheets originating France (where the comma is used as a decimal point) are better-suited to the semiotic analyses developed by [French Deconstructivist philosophers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Derrida), rather than statistical analysis and arithmetic calculation.

---

*You'll be able (or unable) to reproduce this error *some* of the time, depending on your machine locale. And that's today's big lesson: a problem is worsened when it is intermittent, unpredictable, or inconsistently-reproducible.